# Evaluating an integral using Leibnitz theorem

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $$I=\int _0^1 x^m (\log (x))^ndx $$. Evaluate I using Leibnitz theorem.

#### Attempt

I couldnt think of any possible $f (a,x) $ so that $\frac {dI}{da} $ can be calculated the only thing I could see that the result of the integral should be $\frac {(-1)^n}{(m+1)^{n+1}}\gamma (n+1)$ . This was obtained by putting $x=e^t $ and then manoeuvring to get the standard gamma function form.

Comment: Consider $$\int_0^1 x^a\,dx.$$

Comment: Can you enlighten some more on it?

Comment: What does Leibniz' rule give for $$\biggl(\frac{d}{da}\biggr)^k\int_0^1 x^a\,dx\,?$$ And what does evaluating the integral and then differentiating yield?

Comment: Oh got it Thanks for the help. Can you suggest how to come up with such solutions? Is it experience or some useful tricks to be followed?

Comment: Mostly experience. Would you like to write an answer or should I?

Comment: You do the honours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that $\frac{d}{da} x^a = x^a\cdot \log x$ for $x > 0$, we see that

$$\int_0^1 x^m(\log x)^n\,dx = F^{(n)}(m),$$

where

$$F(a) = \int_0^1 x^a\,dx = \frac{1}{a+1}$$

for $a > -1$. From the closed form we obtain

$$F^{(k)}(a) = \frac{(-1)^k\cdot k!}{(a+1)^{k+1}}$$

by induction, so

$$\int_0^1 x^m(\log x)^n\,dx = \frac{(-1)^n\cdot n!}{(m+1)^{n+1}}\,.$$